# Как отследить фокус у двух EditText?

Tags: android

Как можно отследить на каком EditText находится фокус и вывести в TextView То есть если фокус на первом EditText то TextView показывает 1 если на втором то 2

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        if(editText2.requestFocus()){
            textView.setText("1");
        }else if(editText.requestFocus()){
            textView.setText("2");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352209/how-to-find-out-which-view-is-focused

Comment: Есть такая штука, как `google`. Слышали когда-нибудь? https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20focus%20listener&es_th=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requestFocus` это установить фокус на этот элемент.

Чтобы отследить изменение фокуса:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus){
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Чтобы узнать на каком View сейчас фокус - `getCurrentFocus()` у активити.

Comment: Ура!!! Спасибо!!!